# Using same object in different packages

Tags: java, oop

```
  package A;

  //it has a class to connect to a database

  public class refer {
      static connect obj = new connect();
  }
```

I want to use the above object in another package

```
  import A.refer;

  class X {
      public int calculate() {
          int result = refer.obj.methodname();
          return result;
      }
  }
```

Error i am getting- The field refer.obj is not visible.

Comment: different package and default acces modifier = not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use default visibility.

```
 static connect obj=new connect();
```

Acts like a private in other packages. Try

```
   public static connect obj=new connect();
```

Instead.

Comment: that worked, Thanks. I thought default is public .